# How to get values from tables connected thrugh a middle table, using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table A**

| a_id | a_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apples |
| 2 | bananas |
| 3 | cherries |
| 4 | oranges |

**Table B**

| b_id | b_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hot |
| 2 | Cold |

**Table C**

| c_id | a_id | b_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 |

I am trying to get resulting table, which should show "*a_name*" and "*b_name*" with the following condition: `where a_name like '%r%' and b_name like '%o%'`.

Problem is that they should be found within the same row in "*Table_C*".

I've tried various methods of joining tables but I'm unable to get the desired result.

Here's my best coding attempt at this problem:

```
SELECT a.a_name, 
       b.b_name 
FROM Table_A a 
WHERE a.a_name LIKE '%r%' IN (SELECT a.a_id 
                              FROM Table_c 
                              WHERE b_id LIKE '%o');
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: SELECT a.a_name, b.b_name FROM Table_A a WHERE a.a_name LIKE '%r%' IN
(SELECT a.a_id FROM Table_c WHERE b_id LIKE '%o');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you're trying to extract values of "*Table B*" by using a filtering operation (`WHERE` clause). As long as the filtering clause "just filters" - reduces the number of rows of your table - , you can't access "*b.b_name*" inside your `SELECT` clause if the `FROM` contains only "*Table A*".

In this case you may want to use two JOIN operations in place of `WHERE .. IN ..` construct. The main table is "*Table C*" because it connects "*Table A*" and "*Table B*" together. Since you have two conditions to be applied on the names, in order to make this more efficient, you can filter on the two tables ("*Table A*" and "*Table B*") before applying the `JOIN` operation. In this way the DBMS will apply the matching on less rows.

```
SELECT A.a_name,
       B.b_name
FROM       tabC                                         C
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE a_name LIKE '%r%') A
        ON C.a_id = A.a_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabB WHERE b_name LIKE '%o%') B
        ON C.b_id = B.b_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hDv2CcsireATqJf4WVa62e/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   A.a_name,
   B.b_name
from TableA A
inner join TableC C on C.a_id = A.a_id
inner join tableB B on B.b_id = C.b_id
where A.a_name like '%r%' and B.b_name like '%o%';
```

- The inner join '*glues*' the table together on the condition specified after the `ON`
- The where clause is a copy provided by you. I Just added the table aliases for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
select tableA.a_name, tableB.b_name 
from tableC 
left join tableA on tableA.a_id=tableC.a_id 
left join tableB on tableB.b_id=tableC.b_id
where tableA.a_name like '%r%' and tableB.b_name like '%o%'
```